# Implement C# encryption in CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, encryption, cryptojs

I have situation where I need to create the same encryption method which is already up and running in C#. The concept behind this is, from where ever this encrypted key is logged, we will use the same C# project to decrypt it.

Below is the logic used in C#:

```
using var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider
{
Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key),
Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
};
aes.GenerateIV();

using var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
using var cipherStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var tCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var tBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(tCryptoStream))
{
cipherStream.Write(aes.IV);
tBinaryWriter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptMe));
tCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
}
return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherStream.ToArray());
```

Key is the same key used in both C# and JavaScript. But still I am not able to generate the same encryption value as in C#.

I tried to go through other Stack Overflow posts related to this topic, but unable to figure the missing part in JavaScript. Can any one please help?

Comment: What do you mean with "generate the same encryption value" = as you are using a random IV each encrypted data will look different. Second: are you being able to DECRYPT the data on C#-side as you don't expose the IV in the code and the IV is needed for complete/correct decryption ?

Comment: Currently, the CryptoJS code lacks the concatenation of IV and ciphertext. Also, the key material is passed as string, so CryptoJS uses a key derivation function. For the key material to be interpreted as key, it must be parsed into a `WordArray` using one of the CryptoJS encoders.

Comment: @MichaelFehr "generate the same encryption value" - Means I want to follow the same method used in C# in the CryptoJS to produce the encrypted value which can be decrypted in the C# decryption code again. Second: Yes, we are decrypt the encrypted value in C# using C# decryption logic.

Comment: @Topaco Can you please elaborate more or give some code examples

Answer (score 0):

The key used in the C# code is UTF-8 encoded, so on the CryptoJS side the key must be parsed into a `WordArray` using the UTF-8 encoder (CryptoJS only interprets the key material as key if it is passed as a `WordArray`; if it is passed as string, it is interpreted as password and a key derivation function is applied, which would not be compatible with the C# code).
Also, the C# code concatenates IV and ciphertext, which must also happen in the CryptoJS code. This is necessary because the IV is required for decryption.

Fixed code:

```js
var plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('01234567890123456789012345678901'); // Fix 1: parse as WordArray
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv}); // CBC, PKCS#7 padding by default
var ivCiphertext = iv.clone().concat(encrypted.ciphertext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // Fix 2: concatenate IV and ciphertext
console.log(ivCiphertext); // e.g. e9iXcQ2sZ6AA2ne1c3490pAPWOrTGf4UttSSX1lOiKUqwP0oWRPFF83VhZQZMMBu9JKNWIfgS+9D5V39bI4rqg==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

For a test, the ciphertexts cannot simply be compared because, due to the random IV, each encryption produces different ciphertexts.
One option for a test is to *temporarily* use the same IV in the C# code and in the CryptoJS code for the test (and only for the test, since a static IV is insecure!), which would produce the same ciphertexts that could then be compared.
Another option for a test is to decrypt the ciphertext produced with the CryptoJS code with the C# code for decryption.

Comment: I have updated my question, still with the above solution, I am getting the same error as "Padding is invalid". Can you please check the updated question?

Comment: We have made some changes on backend side, so just thought of editing the question. I understand that it has been already answered, but still we get the same error. I will post a new question as you suggested, so that we can get track both code separately. Thank you!

Comment: @sasi - *...but still we get the same error...* The CryptoJS code of this answer is the counterpart to the C# code of the question. As described in my answer, this can be easily verified: With identical IV, the ciphertexts are identical. You can check this online [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TQWeos) and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7crju2k3/).

Comment: I have edited my question ans also posted a new question here. Thank you, I will also try the online links shared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934581/generate-same-encryption-value-using-crypto-js-and-c-sharp-and-decrypt-both-usin